# Measurement Protocol GA4 and session unification

Tags: google-analytics-4

The problem we are trying to solve is to have more accurate purchase reporting with GA4.

We are using [Measurement Protocol GA4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=firebase) to deal with this. The data seems to be very accurate now. But we got two issues:

1. We aren't able to link purchases with the add-to-cart or item-viewed events or user journeys, as the ATC fires from the browser while purchases are sent from server
2. we aren't able to differentiate the one-off and subscription revenue as we fire GA4 POST on order created webhook.

Any suggestions to ensure the events can be linked to each other?